# flock() does not work with the LOCK_NB flag

Tags: php

```
<?php

$fp = fopen('lock.txt', 'r+');
 
if (!flock($fp, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) {
    echo 'Could not get a lock';
    exit(-1);
}
 
echo "The lock has been received";
flush(); // When you add it, it starts working!
sleep(10);
 
fclose($fp);
```

When running two scripts (an example from the official documentation), the second one waits for the end of the first one. But if you add flush() does not wait and returns "Could not get a lock".

Why?

P.S.: Tested on Windows and Linux.

Comment: I tested on Windows' cmd, the second one immediately showed "Could not get a lock". Does this answer your question? [LOCK_NB Ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524073/lock-nb-ignored)