Bug with `LOCK_NB` on PHP
EDIT: I reported this as a bug at https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/14592 - if you think I am doing something wrong, please tell me so I can unreport it.
I am using LOCK_EX and LOCK_SH with PHP and they look to work pretty good. But there is one problem that looks to be a bug (if this is the case, I will report after you guys tell me your opinion).
Save the simple code below to the file test.php, for example.
<?php
$arquivo_lock = fopen("test.txt","a");

if (flock($arquivo_lock,LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB)) { 
    echo "Yes";
} else {
    echo "No";
}

sleep(10);

fclose($arquivo_lock);
?>

Now, in less than 10 seconds apart, open 2 (or more) tabs on your browser calling the file test.php and you will see every tab will show you Yes after some seconds. It should show Yes only on the first tab, all the other should return immediatly with No because I am using LOCK_NB flag - this should be the expected result, however using or not using LOCK_NB makes no change.
I am running this code in CentOS Stream with PHP 8 but I also got this bug to happen on Windows 10 and 11. I also tried opening one tab in Chrome and another tab in Firefox just to make sure the browser was not the curlprit waiting for the firt response to finish to start the second request.

LOCK_SH creates a shared lock, so all the locks succeed. Use LOCK_EX to create an exclusive lock.

@Barmar changing LOCK_SH to LOCK_EX makes absolutely no difference: the bug still happens. Please remove the duplicated flag, because this is not a duplicated of anything in this website

I didn't flag it as a duplicate. @IMSoP did.

Someone posted a comment with a link to a bug report about this, although they've since deleted it.

Thank you for the information, bug could some of you remove the duplicated from this thread? I sinceraly would like to try an answer from the community before annoying the PHP team reporting something that might not be a bug.

It's already been reported as a bug, over 10 years ago. I've put the link and problem description in my answer.

I don't have a full Apache / Nginx install to hand, but running this on PHP 8.2 under Ubuntu with the CLI, or PHP's built-in test server (running twice with php -S localhost:8001 & php -S localhost:8002 &), it works exactly as expected. Note that as written, "No" won't be returned immediately, because you have the sleep(10) regardless of which branch echoes; moving that to only the "Yes" branch, it showed the "No" immediately on the second tab.

If we're agreeing it's the same bug, this should probably be marked duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/5524073/157957 and perhaps a new answer added with the new bug report, and more information about when it doesn't work

This is a bug #54453 in PHP:

LOCK_NB works with LOCK_SH when file locked with LOCK_EX ONLY
LOCK_NB doe NOT work with LOCK_SH if file is locked with LOCK_SH\
LOCK_NB works with LOCK_EX when file locked with LOCK_SH ONLY
LOCK_NB doe NOT work with LOCK_EX if file is locked with LOCK_EX


That bug report is extremely badly written, which is probably why it never got looked at. There's no explanation of expected behaviour, only "it doesn't work", and the sample code has bugs in (the first code block sets LOCK_SH and LOCK_EX at the same time, and the second code block has $fp instead of $x in the fwrite call). More importantly, I can't reproduce either the sample code in this question, or a fixed version of the code in the bug report, when I run under PHP 8.2 CLI. I would be very hesitant to assume an ancient bug report is valid just because nobody closed it.

Since it's consistent with the OP's problem, it seemed reasonable to assume it's the same bug.

But I also can't reproduce this in PHP 7.4 on MacOS or PHP 8.2 on Debian.

@IMSoP I can't reproduce it in CLI, but I did reproduce it in fpm-fcgi

Interesting. In that case, it might be worth opening a new bug with proper steps to reproduce on the current bug tracker (the old one became such a spam magnet it was made read-only).

I'll leave that as an exercise for the OP.

@Barmar I reported the bug as you told me at https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/14592 hope some one takes a look.

@Barmar Since this only seems to be reproducible on some setups, perhaps you could add a comment on the GH issue with the info on the system where you are able to reproduce?

I added my info there.
